# Tab does not navigate after adding MessageBox on the tab's PreviewMouseDown Event

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

i have a WPF tab control with two tabs(A, B). Since there is no `Clicked` Event on the TabItem,therefore i add an `previewMouseDown` event on the Tab B and a `messageBox` will show up. However, after i close the messageBox, my application will not navigate to the Tab B. Anyone can help me?

C# code snippet :

```
  private void MyTabB_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please login");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TabControlSelectionChanged event.

Since you know the selected tab for login say index 0, change selected tab after the MessageBox ie something like this

```
MyTabB_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     TabControl tc= ((TabControl)sender;
     if(tc.SelectedIndex == tc.Items.IndexOf(A/*Login tab*/))
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Login")
         tc.SelectedIndex = tc.Items.IndexOf(B);
      }
}
```

This means whenever you select A you will MessageBox will pop up then you login.

Alternatively why not put a button or any control with ClickedEvent in A then when clicked tc.SelectedIndex is changed.